# CLI Sample Data installation error - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cli, sample-data, data, setup-upgrade

I'm unable to install the Magento 2 sample data via the CLI, this is after Magento 2 has already been installed. Currently on 2.1.1.

The steps I've taken:

1. `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

The `setup:upgrade` command fails with the following error:

```
...
Module 'Magento_GiftMessageStaging':
Module 'Magento_CatalogStaging':
Module 'Magento_GiftRegistrySampleData':
Installing data... PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data/Model/GiftRegistry.php:192
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data/Model/GiftRegistry.php(144): Magento\GiftRegistrySampleData\Model\GiftRegistry->generateData(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data/Setup/Installer.php(30): Magento\GiftRegistrySampleData\Model\GiftRegistry->install(Array)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\GiftRegistrySampleData\Setup\Installer->install()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(171): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SampleData/Executor.php(50): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('setup', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/module in /var/www/vhosts/projectname/production/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data/Model/GiftRegistry.php on line 192
```

Does anyone know how this is resolved? I'm a front-end developer so I'm not too great at spotting the errors in PHP.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Magento didn't update the `data_version` row within the database, all the sample data was set to null. Manually changing these values to 2.0.0 has fixed the problem.

Still no idea what actually caused it though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A suggested fix was posted in this thread.

https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data/issues/25